# power function is giving wrong output in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, math, numbers, pow

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int binary_conversion(int e,int w,int q,int n,int i)
{
  while(abs(w)>=1){//abs(e) to ensure that for negative numbers
    if(abs(w)>=1){
      e=w%2;
      w=w/2;
    }
    else
    {
      w=0;
    }cout<<"i is"<<i<<"\n";cout<<"q is before"<<q<<"\n";
       int r=pow(10,i);cout<<" r is"<<r;
    q=q+pow(10,i)*e;cout<<"q is"<<q<<"\n";
    i++;
 } return q ;
}
int main(){
  int n,w,q=0;int i=0,e;
  cin>>n;w=n;e=n;
  binary_conversion(e,w,q,n,i);
  cout<<q;
}
```

This program converts an integer to a binary digit.
The error that I'm getting in this program is it's not giving 10^i value correctly. The line from where it's not giving the desired output is

```
q=q+pow(10,i)*e;cout<<"q is"<<q<<"\n";
```

the value of `i` in the 3rd iteration is `2` and 10^i should be `100`, but it's `99`.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think `pow` is broken and the problem isn't in *your* code?

Comment: it kind of looks like you're trying to convert an int to another int where each decimal digit of the int is 0 or 1 depending on the corresponding bit in the original int. This will  only work for very small numbers (10 bits or less).

Comment: Your problem may be caused by `pow()` not being exact (same as all floating-point operations). Try `round(pow(10,i))`.

Comment: BTW, if you have a divisor variable, you can multiply or divide in each iteration, rather than having `pow` recalculate every iteration.  Since `pow` is a floating point function, there may be some inaccuracies when converting from floating point to integer or integer to floating point.

Comment: Why does `binary_conversion` have *five* parameters? It looks like you're using parameters where you should be using local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression `10^i` can be expressed iteratively:

```
int power_10 = 1;
int value = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
{
  power = power * 10;
}
```

The above code does not involve floating point so there will be no loss from conversions.

You may want to change your expression evaluation to an iterative method.